# require() no lado do cliente

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Atualmente estou estudando integrações com IBM Watson, mais precisamente o Speech to text, gostaria de integrar essa solução no lado do cliente, pra não precisar fazer requisições ao servidor que fará a requisição para o servidor da IBM.

Gostaria de saber se há uma possibilidade de usar o require('ibm-watson-cloud') no lado do cliente, eu li muita gente falando em webpack, browserify, mas tudo relacionado a gulp e grunt.

Eu hoje estou trabalhando junto ao Asp.Net-Core 2.x, e estou meio perdido com essa questão.

Comment: Alguém ? continuo sem achar a solução.